# Is it true that if $C$ is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^1$ of genus >$0$ and $P,Q\in C$, there does not exist a function $f\in K(C)^*$ with $div(f)=P-Q$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that if $C$ is a curve in $\mathbb{P}^1$ of genus >$0$ and $P$ and $Q$ are two points on $C$, there does not exist a function $f\in K(C)^*$ with $div(f)=P-Q$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by a curve in $\mathbb{P}^1$? Did you mean $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: You probably don't need to talk about an embedding — being complete/projective is enough to say what you want to say, I think. Do you want $C$ to be smooth? Your field is algebraically closed?

Comment: Did you try using Riemann-Roch Theorem?